# How to count how many times user submitted data is present in an article stored in a database question

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I count how many times a user submited word is present in an article stored in my MySQL database and then display the results from the highest to lowest occurrence.

Here is part of my PHP & MySQL code below.

```
$x = 0;
$con = null;
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];

$search_explode = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $search);
$search_explode = explode(' ', $search_explode);

foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if($x == 1){
        $con .= " article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
        $con .= " OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
}

$con = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
              INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
              WHERE ($con) 
              AND users.active IS NULL
              AND users.deletion = 0";

$run =  mysqli_query($dbc, $con);
$search_term = mysqli_num_rows($run);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the article stored as a string in some variable, you can use [`substr_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to find the number of occurrences of a particular string.

If you want general information about words used in the article, you can use [`str_word_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to get a list of all words in the string, and then work with that.

Answer (score 0):

you want to find all occurences of a word in a string:

```
<?php 
function findall($needle, $haystack) 
{ 
    //Setting up 
    $buffer=''; //We will use a 'frameshift' buffer for this search 
    $pos=0; //Pointer 
    $end = strlen($haystack); //The end of the string 
    $getchar=''; //The next character in the string 
    $needlelen=strlen($needle); //The length of the needle to find (speeds up searching) 
    $found = array(); //The array we will store results in 

    while($pos<$end)//Scan file 
    { 
        $getchar = substr($haystack,$pos,1); //Grab next character from pointer 
        if($getchar!="\n" || buffer<$needlelen) //If we fetched a line break, or the buffer is still smaller than the needle, ignore and grab next character 
        { 
            $buffer = $buffer . $getchar; //Build frameshift buffer 
            if(strlen($buffer)>$needlelen) //If the buffer is longer than the needle 
            { 
                $buffer = substr($buffer,-$needlelen);//Truncunate backwards to needle length (backwards so that the frame 'moves') 
            } 
            if($buffer==$needle) //If the buffer matches the needle 
            { 
                $found[]=$pos-$needlelen+1; //Add the location of the needle to the array. Adding one fixes the offset. 
            } 
        } 
        $pos++; //Increment the pointer 
    } 
    if(array_key_exists(0,$found)) //Check for an empty array 
    { 
        return $found; //Return the array of located positions 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; //Or if no instances were found return false 
    } 
} 
?>
```

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

...

and another one :

```
 <?php
function find_occurences($string, $find) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($string), strtolower($find)) !== FALSE) {
        $pos = -1;
        for ($i=0; $i<substr_count(strtolower($string), strtolower($find)); $i++) {
            $pos = strpos(strtolower($string), strtolower($find), $pos+1);
            $positionarray[] = $pos;
        }

        return $positionarray;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

from http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=195567.0

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using Full Text Search. For example:

```
SELECT *,
MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('PHP') AS score
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('PHP')
```

According to the MySQL manual, Full-text is a “natural language search”; it indexes words that appear to represent the row, using the columns you specified. As an example, if all your rows contain “MySQL” then “MySQL” won’t match much. It’s not terribly unique, and it would return too many results. However, if “MySQL” were present in only 5% of the rows, it would return those rows because it doesn’t appear too often to be known as a keyword that’s very common. (If you have “MySQL” in none of your rows, it’ll return nothing; duh.)

MySQL also does something pretty useful. It creates a score. This score is usually something like .9823475 or .124874, but always larger than zero. It can range up above 1, and I have seen it at 4 sometimes. (Don’t try to multiply it by 100 and portray it as a % value; people will wonder why their keyword matches an article 431%!)

MySQL will also order a row by its score, descending.

Another useful tidbit: If you use MATCH() AGAINST() Change the document style for this to “Inline Code” twice in a query, as we will, there is no additional speed penalty. You might expect that because you are executing the same search twice the query would take twice as long, but in fact MySQL remembers the results from the first search as it runs the second.

To learn more see: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304

Comment: I wish I could use Full Text Search but I'm using PHP 5.2 :(

Comment: This is functionality in MySQL and should be agnostic to the PHP version.